# SmoothScroll - problem with the first seconds of scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

why for the first second, the animation is very slow and only after that time has its normal speed.

I would like the speed to be the same from the beginning

This is my first contact with smoothScroll.

```
          <a href="#about" class="navigation__link">about me</a>
          <a href="#skills" class="navigation__link">skills</a>
          <a href="#works" class="navigation__link">my work</a>
```

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

}
```

```
const scroll = new SmoothScroll('.navigation__link[href*="#"]', {
    speed: 800
});
```

Comment: You're using both the native css scroll-behavior and the js script. Try to only use the css (as it is enough) and remove the javascript. Or if you want to have more browser support and speed control, remove the css line and only use js.

Answer (score 0):

Well, There is another way to do that. You can use JavaScript instead of Scroll-Behavior.
For more information, you can click on the blow link :

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp